# How does linux play a piece of music (ALSA)

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I'm interested in 'how to play a tone in linux' recently, because I want to link math and music together. I want to use system calls to do that because that way I don't have to use a music file like `*.mp3` or `*.wav` etc. I've done researches on the internet, but there are only answers for things like 'how to play a music file in a program'.

I thought that there is a device file on linux like leds (`/sys/class/leds/.../brightness`) or usbs (`/dev/usb/`). But there is no `/dev/audio`, `/dev/dsp`, `/dev/sound` on my computer.

So I want to know how linux play a music file, and start from there to achieve my goal.

My question is **NOT** "how to play music [file] in linux", but **INSTEAD** "how linux plays music (ALSA)". Answer on "how to play a tone in program" is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many ways your question is like "could someone explain to me how to catch fish?". There are so many ways and so many tools available, that each answer whilst technically correct, merely illustrates the way that the person answering does it, from the man who works a trawler, through the fly fisher to the spear fisher.
Audio on linux is a subject like water in the Wild West, "Whisky's for drinking, Water's for fighting over".
Just for fun try the following links for an idea of the complexity:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843012

http://alsa.opensrc.org/MultipleCards

But to give you a "Tone" example that can run from the command line (and can be written into code, python and C for certain) load up gstreamer-1.0 on your box and run the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc freq=329.63 volume=0.5 ! autoaudiosink

gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc freq=987.77 ! autoaudiosink

gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc wave=2 freq=200 volume=0.2 ! tee name=t ! queue ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink t. ! queue ! audioconvert ! libvisual_lv_scope ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Then check out:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html

Note: gstreamer is just the fly fisherman's story and that's fighting talk!

Here is some Gtk code for you to play with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, Gtk
class Tone(object):

    def __init__(self):
        window = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Tone-Player")
        window.set_default_size(500, 200)
        window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit, "WM destroy")
        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        window.add(vbox)
        self.tone_entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.tone_entry.set_text('300.00')
        vbox.pack_start(self.tone_entry, False, False, 0)
        self.button = Gtk.Button("Start")
        vbox.add(self.button)
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.start_stop)
        window.show_all()

        self.player = Gst.Pipeline.new("player")
        source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audiotestsrc", "tone-source")
        audioconv = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "converter")
        audiosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink", "audio-output")
        self.player.add(source)
        self.player.add(audioconv)
        self.player.add(audiosink)
        source.link(audioconv)
        audioconv.link(audiosink)

    def start_stop(self, w):
        if self.button.get_label() == "Start":
                self.button.set_label("Stop")
                tone = float(self.tone_entry.get_text())
                self.player.get_by_name("tone-source").set_property("freq", tone)
                self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        else:
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            self.button.set_label("Start")

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
Tone()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Is there a way to play two freq at a time?

Comment: At its simplest create self.player2 in the same way as self.player which will give a combined output. I guess there is probably a way to split them left and right but your would have to do your own research.

Comment: What are the use of the `audioconv` and `audiosink`?

Comment: They are just variable names to which have been assigned gstreamer's audioconvert and autoaudiosink functions respectively. Audioconvert converts raw audio buffers between various possible formats and arguably in this scenario isn't required. Autoaudiosink is the output, where an appropriate audio sink is automatically detected on your machine. See: the gstreamer link that I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/) is a kernel driver that provides support for numerous sound cards. It is usually used by low-level applications that want to interact with the sound system quite directly.

ALSA offers a [library API](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/) that you can use. Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Documentation) for some examples and help in the right direction.

With ALSA you can access a buffer, and put samples into it, that will be played by the sound device. This is done with PCM (Pulse-code modulation). With ALSA you have a lot to configure (as seen [here](http://users.suse.com/~mana/alsa090_howto.html)). You want to configure the amount of channels (mono, stereo, etc.), size of the samples (8 bit, 16 bit, etc.), the rate (8000 Hz, 16000 Hz, 44100 Hz, etc.). You write those samples to the PCM device with `snd_pcm_writei`, for example.

The definitions of the ALSA library are located in `alsa/asoundlib.h`. If you're using GCC, then you can link with the ALSA library with `-lasound`.

Not all music players would use these low-level interactions. Much software is build on top of ALSA to give more generic interfaces to the sound system (platform independent even). Examples of sound servers include [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) and [PulseAudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/). The advantage of these sound servers is that they are usually easier to set-up and use, but do not give the fine control you would have with ALSA.

Comment: Should I include the header `alsa/asoundlib.h` to use the function? or is that the file? And, is that the method how most music players will use?

Comment: Got it. And since you mentioned `pulseaudio`, does it have a library too? Can you provide that infomation too?

Comment: @Chromium I'm not familiar with the details of PulseAudio, but [PulseAudio documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821201/playing-a-wav-file-using-pulseaudio-apis) should bring you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. But the [link](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) in the question you mentioned is broken.

Comment: @Chromium Be creative and find other resources. Google 'wav format' and it should lead you to plenty of useful sources.

Comment: with the tutorial of ALSA you provide, I try to use the `miniFMsynth.c` it provides. But when I compile, a lot of variables and functions are not defined, including `snd_pcm_writei`. Is that indicates a problem? Note: I only have a `sound/asound.h`, and a link it to `alsa/asoundlib.h`.

Comment: Open a new question, and I'd be glad to help. I don't think you fully understand linking and what header files are. You can't 'link' to a header file. The functions should be declared, but might not be defined when you link it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

in order that LINUX will play sound (any kind, such mp3/wave/etc.) it use a library could ALSA. see [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page).
The ASLA project support many soundcards and you can see in their WiKi some tips of how to see if your soundcard is supported and how to test it.

If you are going to add a driver for a new soundcard you should keep in mind that there are 2 separate flows that need to be handled:

1. configure the HW (CODEC) - usually this is made by I2C bus and this configure the h/w. for example: set equalizer, set/mono/stero, set set analog amplifiers and so on.
2. data flow - the data is the actual streaming of the file from the linux stack to the h/w. you will need to create buffers and so on to handle the streaming and you could use the ALSA APIs for start/stop record/play

this is extremely vast field so it is better to see some already exists examples before trying to write your own driver.
try to add prints along the ALSA code to see what is going on when starting to play an audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some c code which populates a memory buffer with audio data which is then rendered using OpenAL - no audio file

```
//    sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev 
//
//    gcc -o   gen_tone    gen_tone.c  -lopenal  -lm
// 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    // gives malloc
#include <math.h>


#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenAL/al.h>
#include <OpenAL/alc.h>
#elif __linux
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#endif

ALCdevice  * openal_output_device;
ALCcontext * openal_output_context;

ALuint internal_buffer;
ALuint streaming_source[1];

int al_check_error(const char * given_label) {

    ALenum al_error;
    al_error = alGetError();

    if(AL_NO_ERROR != al_error) {

        printf("ERROR - %s  (%s)\n", alGetString(al_error), given_label);
        return al_error;
    }
    return 0;
}

void MM_init_al() {

    const char * defname = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);

    openal_output_device  = alcOpenDevice(defname);
    openal_output_context = alcCreateContext(openal_output_device, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(openal_output_context);

    // setup buffer and source

    alGenBuffers(1, & internal_buffer);
    al_check_error("failed call to alGenBuffers");
}

void MM_exit_al() {

    ALenum errorCode = 0;

    // Stop the sources
    alSourceStopv(1, & streaming_source[0]);        //      streaming_source
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < 1; ++ii) {
        alSourcei(streaming_source[ii], AL_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    // Clean-up
    alDeleteSources(1, &streaming_source[0]);
    alDeleteBuffers(16, &streaming_source[0]);
    errorCode = alGetError();
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    errorCode = alGetError();
    alcDestroyContext(openal_output_context);
    alcCloseDevice(openal_output_device);
}

void MM_render_one_buffer() {

    /* Fill buffer with Sine-Wave */
    // float freq = 440.f;
    float freq = 850.f;
    float incr_freq = 0.1f;

    int seconds = 4;
    // unsigned sample_rate = 22050;
    unsigned sample_rate = 44100;
    double my_pi = 3.14159;
    size_t buf_size = seconds * sample_rate;

    short * samples = malloc(sizeof(short) * buf_size);

   printf("\nhere is freq %f\n", freq);
    int i=0;
    for(; i<buf_size; ++i) {
        samples[i] = 32760 * sin( (2.f * my_pi * freq)/sample_rate * i );

        freq += incr_freq;
        // incr_freq += incr_freq;
        // freq *= factor_freq;

        if (100.0 > freq || freq > 5000.0) {

            incr_freq *= -1.0f;
        }
    }

    /* upload buffer to OpenAL */
    alBufferData( internal_buffer, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, samples, buf_size, sample_rate);
    al_check_error("populating alBufferData");

    free(samples);

    /* Set-up sound source and play buffer */
    // ALuint src = 0;
    // alGenSources(1, &src);
    // alSourcei(src, AL_BUFFER, internal_buffer);
    alGenSources(1, & streaming_source[0]);
    alSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_BUFFER, internal_buffer);
    // alSourcePlay(src);
    alSourcePlay(streaming_source[0]);

    // ---------------------

    ALenum current_playing_state;
    alGetSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_SOURCE_STATE, & current_playing_state);
    al_check_error("alGetSourcei AL_SOURCE_STATE");

    while (AL_PLAYING == current_playing_state) {

        printf("still playing ... so sleep\n");

        sleep(1);   // should use a thread sleep NOT sleep() for a more responsive finish

        alGetSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_SOURCE_STATE, & current_playing_state);
        al_check_error("alGetSourcei AL_SOURCE_STATE");
    }

    printf("end of playing\n");

    /* Dealloc OpenAL */
    MM_exit_al();

}   //  MM_render_one_buffer

int main() {

    MM_init_al();

    MM_render_one_buffer();
}
```

its also possible to convert this into a audio server which renders audio while the memory buffer is repeatedly populated